# How can I make sure a shed is hurricane rated?

Tags: structural, shed

I need to build a metal shed about 10' high and 6x6 in floor space which must be able to withstand 175 MPH winds.

How can I make sure that the shed and its anchors can hold up under those conditions?

Comment: Are you looking to buy a kit or roll your own design? In the case of the latter, I'm pretty sure you're looking at getting a structural engineer to certify the structure for hurricane loads

Comment: I don't know a lot about this, but I found this site where you can search for approved shed plans in Florida. [Search here](https://floridabuilding.org/mb/mb_plan_srch.aspx) and you can find full blueprints of shed designs that come with wind ratings, and it's Florida, so they see their fair share of actual hurricanes.

Comment: The answer is going to depend on your design. As it is, the question is too broad.

Comment: Wow only 6x6 and 10 feet tall, that is going to have one heck of a frame work and a really thick pad or deep pileings that the frame work attaches to. Makes me think of a telephone pole and think how many of those get broken off ,

Comment: Seriously, is *earth sheltered* construction out of the question?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options that should work...

## Shipping Container

A steel shipping container should be more than strong enough to meet hurricane ratings, and come in just about any size.

[image]

[This company](https://americanearthanchors.com/which-anchor-should-i-use/hurricanes-storms/) sells anchors that it claims should withstand strong winds & hurricanes, though they "have not been *scientifically* tested." They're basically big triangles of metal or long screws driven into the ground:

[image][image]

## Monolithic Dome (shed sized)

A dome constructed of rebar, foam & concrete/shotcrete. They're very very resistant to winds (probably tornadoes too), and the weight combined with a cement slab & footing should make sure the whole thing won't blow away, ever. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_dome) or [Inhabitat.com](https://inhabitat.com/monolithic-domes/)

[image]

[Alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Wind-resistant-and-anti-seismic-prefabricated_60430184130.html) has a larger one, with images too:

[image]

---

For more conventional construction, if your neighbourhood/city has hurricane requirements then they must have guidelines on how to meet them, especially for usually DIY-friendly sheds. Check with them first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert about coastal or island wind zones (mostly just the normal tornado/high wind stuff), but I can tell you that having a continuous load path and paying attention to uplift are important.

Having a continuous load path means that you transfer all vertical and lateral loads from the wood structure down to the foundation, usually by using hangers and/or fasteners to make the connections. This means that fastener & hanger manufacturers should have many of the resources you're looking for.

Simpson Strong-Tie (a fastener and hanger manufacturer) have a lot of stuff that might help if you're willing to teach yourself. They have a [homeowner focused website](http://www.safestronghome.com/), as well as [a PDF for builders](https://www.strongtie.com/resources/literature/high-wind-product-guide).

The main idea is to make sure that no matter what the wind does (push/pull/twists/racks) to the wood structure, that the structure will be able to use the foundation to resist those forces.

It's easy to overbuild your shed using a metal connector at every point, and that is what Simpson wants you to do. You would need an engineer to tell you which of these steps don't need a metal connector and where nails would be sufficient based on your specific location and exposure category:

1. Connect your bottom sill plate to your foundation, and your studs to the bottom sill plate.
2. Connect your top plate to your studs.
3. Connect your rafters/trusses to your top plate.

[image: Connect your bottom sill plate to your foundation, and your studs to the bottom sill plate.]
[image: Connect your top plate to your studs.]
[image: Connect your rafters/trusses to your top plate.]